# Determine type from string of type to read binary data in swift

Tags: swift, types, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have terabytes of Binary data written from a C++ application, sparse data with coordinates and 4 Floats. I am now writing an application in swift to read that data.  The binary data is repetitive, e.g. `UInt8, UInt8, Float32, Float32, Float32, Float32...`. When writing the data about 12 months ago, I included a separate json file describing the data. I now need to use those String representations of Type to call a function in swift to read the binary file.

```swift
//A string representation of the type of binary data stored on disk
struct dimJSON{
    let diskColRowType: String = "UInt8"
    let diskQType: String = "Float32"
    var sizeColRowTypeInBytes:Int {
       if diskColRowType = "UInt8" {return 1}
    ...etc
}

//The function used to read the data
func readBinaryData<diskColRow: BinaryInteger, diskQ: BinaryFloatingPoint>(diskColRow: diskColRow.Type, diskQ: diskQ.Type) -> [[[diskQ]]]{

    var plane = [[[diskQ]]]()

    data.withUnsafeBytes{ (ptr: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
        for index in stride(from: 0, to: dim.binFileSizeInStructs * dim.sizeStructInBytes, by: dim.sizeStructInBytes) {


        let col = Int(ptr.load(fromByteOffset: index, as: diskColRow.self))
        let row = Int(ptr.load(fromByteOffset: index + dim.sizeColRowTypeInBytes, as: diskColRow.self))

        //Cannot ptr.load bytes offset, due to possible unaligned memory
        let q = Data(bytes: ptr.baseAddress!.advanced(by: index + dim.byteOffsetQVec), count: 4 * dim.sizeQTypeInBytes)

        plane[col][row] = q.toArray(type: diskQ.self)

        }
    }
    return plane
}


//This works, but seems dull, and I have multiple call sites for similar funcs readBinaryData.

if dim.diskColRowType == "UInt8" && dim.diskQ == "Float32"{
    let p = readBinaryData(diskColRow: UInt8.self, diskQ: Float32.self)
} else if dim.diskColRowType == "UInt16" && dim.diskQ == "Double" {
    let p = readBinaryData(diskColRow: UInt16.self, diskQ: Double.self)
}

//Something like this would be good:
extension dimJSON {
    func getType() -> ?????? {
        if diskColRowType = "UInt8" {return UInt8.self}
        else if diskColRowType = "UInt16" {return UInt16.self}
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how did you get to this point without reading the basics of the Swift language

Comment: You are more than welcome to contribute Leo...

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to start your structures, classes and protocols names  with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Thank you for your valued contribution.